# Firefox addon to change browser tracking?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is there a firefox addon that could change FireFox tracking? 
As in if I visit a website and it shows I am using Firefox but when I apply this addon it could show as Chrome or IE

Comment: What ethical use do you have for this?

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about). Please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.  Please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for an addon to change the User Agent string.
You'll find such addons on https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/ just seaching for `User Agent`.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Which can load data from .txt file or .xml file?